# 'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: composer-php

`'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: How did you install composer? Did you restart the CMD prompt? What is the complete value of `PATH`?

Comment: @WouterJ is right for "Did you restart the CMD prompt?". You need to restart your CMD port. Then only you can get composer command available.

Comment: Use Linux or MacOS for development. So much more convenient. Use a docker container or Virtualbox if you don’t want or can’t switch your main OS. Almost the whole toolchain for PHP is made for *nix, Windows will always require a billion of workarounds and hacks which will consume so much of your precious time. Have a look at this article https://link.medium.com/xxH3pb4duR

Answer (score 25):

For anyone still reading seeking answer (like I did when I found this): simply restarting cmd prompt will not work, you have to restart **Windows Explorer or your computer** and then both composer and php will work globally.

Answer (score 6):

go to `C:\wamp\www\laravel\` in the command prompt,
use `"C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer install"` instead of `"composer install"`

Comment: Either you can try steps listed on http://leedavis81.github.io/global-installation-of-composer-on-windows/

Since the way you are suggesting is not so useful while laravel new creating project, it will call composer and you will find error

Answer (score 0):

> Right Click My PC Icon select propertise
>
> Advance System Setting
>
> -> Advance tab -> Environment variables
>
> -> System Variable -> Click path ->
>
> ->Add Line ->  `C:\composer`